# Kinesis Spark Streaming longevity issues

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I'm having issues with the longevity of Spark-Kinesis Streaming application running on spark standalone cluster manager. The program runs for around 50 hours and stops receiving data from kinesis without giving any valid error why it stopped. But if i restart the application, it works for another day and half or so.

I'm seeing whole lot of errors during the program execution. I'm not sure this is the related to unexpected stoppage of events. Because these errors are there in logs even when the spark application is working fine.

There is no error specific to stoppage in driver or executor.Also I checked if there is any out of memory error but I was not able to spot in the logs. Could you please help me understand what are these error message means? Is this having anything to do with the longevity? Where do you think i should debug to understand whats happening with this?

```
  2016-04-15 13:32:19 INFO  KinesisRecordProcessor:58 - Shutdown:  Shutting down workerId ip-10-205-1-150.us-west-2.compute.internal:6394789f-acb9-4702-8ea2-c2a3637d925a with reason       ZOMBIE
  2016-04-15 13:32:19 ERROR ShutdownTask:123 - Application exception.
  java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.hash(ConcurrentHashMap.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.remove(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1175)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisCheckpointer.removeCheckpointer(KinesisCheckpointer.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisReceiver.removeCheckpointer(KinesisReceiver.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisRecordProcessor.shutdown(KinesisRecordProcessor.scala:124)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.V1ToV2RecordProcessorAdapter.shutdown(V1ToV2RecordProcessorAdapter.java:48)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.ShutdownTask.call(ShutdownTask.java:94)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.call(MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.java:48)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.call(MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.java:23)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  2016-04-15 13:32:19 ERROR ShutdownTask:123 - Application exception.
  java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.hash(ConcurrentHashMap.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.remove(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1175)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisCheckpointer.removeCheckpointer(KinesisCheckpointer.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisReceiver.removeCheckpointer(KinesisReceiver.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisRecordProcessor.shutdown(KinesisRecordProcessor.scala:124)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.V1ToV2RecordProcessorAdapter.shutdown(V1ToV2RecordProcessorAdapter.java:48)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.ShutdownTask.call(ShutdownTask.java:94)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.call(MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.java:48)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.call(MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.java:23)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  016-04-15 13:33:12 INFO  LeaseRenewer:235 - Worker ip-10-205-1-151.us-west-2.compute.internal:188bd3f5-095b-405f-ac9f-b7eff11e16d1 lost lease with key shardId-000000000046 -       discovered during update
  2016-04-15 13:33:12 WARN  MetricsHelper:67 - No metrics scope set in thread RecurringTimer - Kinesis Checkpointer - Worker ip-10-205-1-151.us-west-2.compute.internal:188bd3f5-     095b-405f-ac9f-b7eff11e16d1, getMetricsScope returning NullMetricsScope.
  2016-04-15 13:33:12 ERROR KinesisRecordProcessor:95 - ShutdownException:  Caught shutdown exception, skipping checkpoint.
  com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.exceptions.ShutdownException: Can't update checkpoint - instance doesn't hold the lease for this shard
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.KinesisClientLibLeaseCoordinator.setCheckpoint(KinesisClientLibLeaseCoordinator.java:120)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.RecordProcessorCheckpointer.advancePosition(RecordProcessorCheckpointer.java:216)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.RecordProcessorCheckpointer.checkpoint(RecordProcessorCheckpointer.java:137)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.RecordProcessorCheckpointer.checkpoint(RecordProcessorCheckpointer.java:103)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisCheckpointer$$anonfun$checkpoint$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(KinesisCheckpointer.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisCheckpointer$$anonfun$checkpoint$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(KinesisCheckpointer.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisCheckpointer$$anonfun$checkpoint$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(KinesisCheckpointer.scala:81)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisRecordProcessor$.retryRandom(KinesisRecordProcessor.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisCheckpointer$$anonfun$checkpoint$1.apply(KinesisCheckpointer.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisCheckpointer$$anonfun$checkpoint$1.apply(KinesisCheckpointer.scala:75)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisCheckpointer.checkpoint(KinesisCheckpointer.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisCheckpointer.org$apache$spark$streaming$kinesis$KinesisCheckpointer$$checkpointAll(KinesisCheckpointer.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisCheckpointer$$anonfun$1.apply$mcVJ$sp(KinesisCheckpointer.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.util.RecurringTimer.triggerActionForNextInterval(RecurringTimer.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.util.RecurringTimer.org$apache$spark$streaming$util$RecurringTimer$$loop(RecurringTimer.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.util.RecurringTimer$$anon$1.run(RecurringTimer.scala:29)
  2016-04-15 13:33:12 WARN  KinesisCheckpointer:91 - Failed to checkpoint shardId shardId-000000000046 to DynamoDB.
  com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.exceptions.ShutdownException: Can't update checkpoint - instance doesn't hold the lease for this shard
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.KinesisClientLibLeaseCoordinator.setCheckpoint(KinesisClientLibLeaseCoordinator.java:120)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.RecordProcessorCheckpointer.advancePosition(RecordProcessorCheckpointer.java:216)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.RecordProcessorCheckpointer.checkpoint(RecordProcessorCheckpointer.java:137)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.RecordProcessorCheckpointer.checkpoint(RecordProcessorCheckpointer.java:103)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisCheckpointer$$anonfun$checkpoint$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(KinesisCheckpointer.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisCheckpointer$$anonfun$checkpoint$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(KinesisCheckpointer.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisCheckpointer$$anonfun$checkpoint$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(KinesisCheckpointer.scala:81)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisRecordProcessor$.retryRandom(KinesisRecordProcessor.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisCheckpointer$$anonfun$checkpoint$1.apply(KinesisCheckpointer.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisCheckpointer$$anonfun$checkpoint$1.apply(KinesisCheckpointer.scala:75)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisCheckpointer.checkpoint(KinesisCheckpointer.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisCheckpointer.org$apache$spark$streaming$kinesis$KinesisCheckpointer$$checkpointAll(KinesisCheckpointer.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisCheckpointer$$anonfun$1.apply$mcVJ$sp(KinesisCheckpointer.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.util.RecurringTimer.triggerActionForNextInterval(RecurringTimer.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.util.RecurringTimer.org$apache$spark$streaming$util$RecurringTimer$$loop(RecurringTimer.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.util.RecurringTimer$$anon$1.run(RecurringTimer.scala:29)
  2016-04-15 13:33:12 INFO  LeaseRenewer:116 - Worker ip-10-205-1-151.us-west-2.compute.internal:188bd3f5-095b-405f-ac9f-b7eff11e16d1 lost lease with key shardId-000000000046
  2016-04-15 13:33:12 INFO  MemoryStore:58 - Block input-2-1460727103359 stored as values in memory (estimated size 120.3 KB, free 171.8 MB)
```

Comment: Can you check to see if your nodes are still alive? A while back we had a simular issue that was caused by ever growing log files (for the history server as far as I remember). Everything ran fine for about a day and a half and then just stopped working.

Comment: You can disable logging with `spark.eventLog.enabled=false`